# How to programmatically determine the height of UIStackView after a subview has been hidden swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am using a UIStackView within a UIScrollView and I want to determine the height of the stack view so I can programmatically adjust the height of the scrollview to accomodate when subviews are hidden.

I am using

```
stackView.frame.height
```

to determine stack view height. This is called in `viewDidLoad()` but it is always the same height value from the storyboard no matter if subviews are hidden or not.

How do I determine height?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon. Try `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After making layout changes to any view, it has to recalculate it's frame after the function is completed. To get the updated frame right away, call:

```
stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Example:

```
print(stackView.frame.height) // old height
subview1.isHidden = true
print(stackView.frame.height) // still old height
stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
print(stackView.frame.height) // new height
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still receive the old height after .layoutIfNeeded().

Comment: @Khoury Have you tried removing the arranged subview altogether (not just hiding it) to see if that changes the height?

Comment: I changed it just now from hiding to .removeFromSuperview(), still no change in height?

Comment: @Khoury you need to call `setNeedsLayout()` *before* `.layoutIfNeeded()`, then get the frame height.

Comment: @Khoury instead of removeFromSuperview() try `stackview.removeArrangedSubview(subview1)`

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me either.